# Xpath error while trying for generating any random email generator using Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide, xpath

I am trying to run a script but there is an element not found error. Xpath not get detected by Selenium. I am trying to generate email address randomly.

Each time there is an error that [error] Element .//*[@id='GmailAddress'] not found. Where ".//*[@id='GmailAddress'" is Xpath of the desired text field. JavaScript is here for that specified fraction:

`Selenium.prototype.doGenerateRandomEmail= function(locator)
   {
    Selenium.doType(locator,"gunjanrana123@gmail.com");
   }`

I just need that "gunjanrana123@gmail.com" address appear in text field when I run Selenium IDE.

Kindly tell where is the problem either in JavaScript or in Selenium command.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

`//[@id='GmailAddress']` to: `//*[@id='GmailAddress']`. You are missing an `*` in your code.